# why my ESP8266 http request return -5 while calling mongodb endpoint API

Tags: mongodb, api, embedded, esp8266, endpoint

I have mention my ESP8266 code below...
httpClient in ESP8266 is returning -5 when calling Mongo DB atlas Data endpoint API
while sending text in Serial port that API will be execute but not returned expected output, I will got response from http code is `-5`.

**ESP8266 code**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

String ssid = "laptop";
String password = "saravanan";
String serverName = "https://ap-south-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-ggh8c/endpoint/modifyProduct";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(WL_CONNECTED);
    Serial.println(WiFi.status());
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    String message = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println("Received message: " + message);

    HTTPClient http;
    WiFiClient wifi_client;

    http.begin(wifi_client,serverName);
    http.addHeader("api-key", "9gQC6asgadsfawe2pfNMpzmfsqtyEbasdfwAET9aRiL8FcyWvDYlvXx");
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "plain/text");

    
    String data = "key1=value1&key2=value2";
    int httpCode = http.POST(data);
    String response = http.getString();

    Serial.println("HTTP Response code: " + String(httpCode));
    Serial.println("HTTP Response body: " + response);
 
    http.end();
  }
}
```

Actual expected to get an output string "HI", *I have already write a function in mongo db endpoint it will simply return 'HI'*, I'm also verified in `postman` its working good, but it's not work in ESP8266.
if iam send any message('hello') in Serial

**Output** in serial monitor

```
13:58:23.309 -> 3
13:58:23.309 -> 7
13:58:23.309 -> Connecting to WiFi...
13:58:24.298 -> 3
13:58:24.298 -> 3
13:58:24.298 -> Connecting to WiFi...
13:58:24.298 -> Connected to WiFi
14:00:17.884 -> Received message: `hello`
14:00:18.869 -> HTTP Response code: -5
14:00:18.869 -> HTTP Response body:
```

Comment: You're trying to connect to an HTTPS server with HTTP. That won't work. Refer to the [HTTPClient examples](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples).